# The file Form1 cannot be modified at this time

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, edit, design-time

Opening a Visual Studio 2015 project and in Design-Time modifying a form designer or code I get this error:

> ------------------
>   Microsoft Visual Studio
>   ---------------------------
>   The file C:\TFS...\Form1.cs cannot be modified at this time.
>   ---------------------------
>   OK ---------------------------

Its a bug discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4039 and the solutions are not applicable:

**a) convert your workspace into a local workspace.**

It is a local workspace.

**b) Check-out the form before opening it in the designer/code editor.**

It is checked out.

---

In addition this MSDN article: [The designer cannot be modified at this time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kcbhat9(v=vs.100).aspx) is not applicable:

**c) Ensure that the file is not marked read-only and the solution is not running.**

The file is read/write and the solution is not running.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the same problem after converting from a server workspace back to a local workspace. Deleting the vssscc file may be the best option but I'll document what I did.

1. Checked in file in question.
2. Opened Visual Studio 2015 command prompt and ran:

   ```
   tf lock /lock:none /workspace:DEV02LOCAL "$/Web/.../frmMain.cs"
   ```
3. Checked out file

I'd be interested to see if attempting to re-checkout resolves the problem in this case:

```
tf lock /lock:checkout /workspace:DEV02LOCAL "$/Web/.../frmMain.cs"
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Note: Answering my own question for Community as wiki.</sub>

Deleting the vssscc file, start (F5) and stopping the project allowed me to edit the form.